# dnn 5 module programming

Tags: dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I'm starting to get into dnn 5 module programming (using dnn for the very first time). 
The issue is i can't seem to be able to use my new module. i programm it, then apparently y install it, but when i try to add it to a pane in the page, the page loads, but no module appears. i try to install it again, but a tag reads "it's allready installed".

i've followed instructions for doing this, for dnn 4, but there seems to be something different in the procedure to follow.

Here are the instructions i "adapted" to dnn 5: 
http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2008/05/29/dotnetnuke-modules-registering-your-module/

I hope some one can tell me what i am doing wrong, or more likely, what should i change in the instructions followed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and if it fails, please post the module definition. (.dnn file)

I did my first dnn 5 module last week - I created the new module definition directly from the dnn host admin area and didn't add any controls. Once I added the controls, my module still didn't appear because all my controls had a "key" defined.

You need to make sure that 1 control in your module definition is added "without" a key - this is the default view (ascx) that will load for you.

Comment: i'll try it asap and tell you... thnx either way.